# predictions with Bayesian network

Tags: bayesian, inference

I am new with bayesian network, i have a project to create intelligent tutoring system with bayesian inference assessment. I want to know that can I make prediction for each student for his/her previous records ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.
First of all, you need to answer these questions:
Do you have the historical data for predictor variables and outcome?
What kind of variables you want to use?
What kind of causal relationship you have that effect the outcome?
Do you know the conditional dependencies (probabilities) between the variables?
If you give more information, you will get more answers.
Good luck